# Python [[0]] meaning

Tags: python, pandas, kaggle

I am running a Python script (Kaggle script).  It works in a 3.4.5 virtualenv, but not in 3.5.2

I am not sure why and I am not familiar with the [[0]] syntax.  Below is the snippet.

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv(r'path\train.csv')
labels_flat = data[[0]].values.ravel()
```

It should produce a list of values from the csv's first column.

In 3.5.2 I get this error:

```
KeyError: '[0] not in index'
```

I tried to replicate the value with

```
labels_flat = []
lf = data.values.tolist()
for row in lf:
    labels_flat.append(row[0])
```

But I don't think it is the same thing.

Comment: Then you need to use `data[0]` not `data[[0]]`.

Comment: No, it is a dataframe, not a list.  having data[0] produces the error "KeyError: 0".  This behavior occurs in both 3.4.5 and 3.5.2

Comment: The non-ambiguous way to get the first column by integer index is `data.iloc[:, 0]`.

Comment: Place that as the answer and I will accept it Igor Raush.  That worked on 3.4.5 and 3.5.2.  I am still not sure about the [[0]] syntax.  An explanation would be great.

Comment: @ChadCrowe Print out df.columns. What do you see?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ it prints out the dataframe's columns.  Index(['label', 'pixel0', 'pixel1', 'pixel2', 'pixel3', 'pixel4', 'pixel5',
       'pixel6', 'pixel7', 'pixel8',
       ...
       'pixel774', 'pixel775', 'pixel776', 'pixel777', 'pixel778', 'pixel779',
       'pixel780', 'pixel781', 'pixel782', 'pixel783'],
      dtype='object', length=785)  This is for a 28x28 picture MNIST dataset in Kaggle.  The first column is the correct label for this training data.

Comment: @ChadCrowe In that case you must index it by data[['label']] or else use iloc as mentioned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I dont think the problem is with the syntax, your Dataframe just does not contain the index you are looking for.

For me this works:

```
In [1]: data = pd.DataFrame({0:[1,2,3], 1:[4,5,6], 2:[7,8,9]})
In [2]: data[[0]]
Out[2]: 
   0
0  1
1  2
2  3
```

I think what confuses you about the `[[0]]` syntax is that the squared brackets are used in python for two completely different things, and the `[[0]]` statement uses both:

**A.** `[]` is used to create a list. In the above example `[0]` creates a list with the single element `0`.

**B.** `[]` is also used to access an element from a list (or dict,...). So `data[0]` returns the 0.-th element of `data`.

The next confusion thing is that while the usual python lists are indexed by numbers (eg. `data[4]` is the 4. element of `data`), Pandas Dataframes can be indexed by lists. This is syntactic sugar to easily access multiple columns of the dataframe at once.
So in my example from above, to get column `0` and `1` you can do:

```
In [3]: data[[0, 1]]
Out[3]: 
   0  1
0  1  4
1  2  5
2  3  6
```

Here the inner `[0, 1]` creates a list with the elements `0` and `1`. The outer `[   ]` retrieve the columns of the dataframe by using the inner list as an index.

For more readability look at this, its the exact same:

```
In [4]: l = [0, 1]

In [5]: data[l]
Out[5]: 
   0  1
0  1  4
1  2  5
2  3  6
```

If you only want the first column (column `0`) you get this:

```
In [6]: data[[0]]
Out[6]: 
   0
0  1
1  2
2  3
```

Which is exactly what you were looking for.